# Prepared Statement Execution in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    /*
     * 1.load the driver
     * driver class :com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

     */

    try {
        Driver driverref=new Driver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driverref);
        /*
         * 2.get db connection via driver
         */
        String DbUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/college?user=suhas&password=j2ee";
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(DbUrl);
        /*
         * 3.issue SQL queries via Connection
         */
        String query="select * from Students_info where regno=?"
         +"firstname=?";
        pstmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
        String regnum=args[0];
        int regno=Integer.parseInt(regnum);
        pstmt.setInt(1,regno);
        pstmt.setString(2, args[1]);
        rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
        /*
         * 4.process the results returned by sql query
         */
        while(rs.next()){
            int dbregno=rs.getInt("regno");
            String fname=rs.getString("firstname");
            String mname=rs.getString("middlename");
            String lname=rs.getString("lastname");
            System.out.println("regno "+dbregno);
            System.out.println("first name "+fname );
            System.out.println("middlename "+mname);
            System.out.println("lastname "+lname);
            }//end of while
    }
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        /*
         * close all jdbc objects
         */
        try {
            if(con!=null){
                con.close();

            }
            if(pstmt!=null){
                pstmt.close();
            }
            if(rs!=null){
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}
with the above code am not able to pass the args value in run configurations.Am getting an number format exception how to fix this.How to pass the args in Arguments tab of run configurations.

Comment: i am passing the argument from run configuration  @peeskillet

Comment: The code looks fine. What line is giving you the exception?

Comment: And what are you typing in exactly?

Comment: am typing 5,name1 in run configurations tab the exception is as follows
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5,suhas"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at com.first.Preparedstatement.main(Preparedstatement.java:38)
@peeskillet

Comment: command line arguments are separated by a white space, not by a comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a closer look at your code:

```java
String query="select * from Students_info where regno=?"
         +"firstname=?";
```

is exactly equivalent to

```java
String query="select * from Students_info where regno=?firstname=?";
```

Let's pretend that when you substitute your query parameters `regno = 1` and `args[1] = "Gord"`. The requlting SQL query will look like this:

```sql
select * from Students_info where regno=1firstname='Gord'
```

That is not valid syntax. The two conditions in the WHERE clause need to be combined using a boolean operator: `AND` or `OR`. So, your original query string needs to be either

```java
String query="select * from Students_info where regno=?"
         +" AND firstname=?";
```

or

```java
String query="select * from Students_info where regno=?"
         +" OR firstname=?";
```